# It is not going inside the first loop and only printing I am outside loop only

Tags: java, for-loop

The below code is not giving any error. After debugging i found it is not going inside the first loop.

```
 package string_pattern;

    public class Naive {
    
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            String pattern="This is a text book";
            String text="text";
            child obj=new child();
            obj.search(pattern, text);
        }
    }

    
 class child{
    public void search(String pat,String text)
    {
        int m,n;
        m=pat.length();
        n=text.length();
        System.out.println("i am outside loop");
        for(int i=0; i<= (n-m); i++)
        {
            int j;
            System.out.println("i am inside first loop"); 
            for(j=0;j<m;j++)
            {
                if(text.charAt(i+j) != pat.charAt(j))
                {
                System.out.println("OVER HERE");
                    break;
                
                }
                if(j==m)
                    System.out.println("pattern found at pos" + i);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: ..and the question is..?

Answer (score 1):

You do the following:

```
m=pat.length();
n=text.length();
```

The problem is that `text` has a length of 4, while `pat` is longer. So when you do the loop like this -> `for(int i=0; i<= (n-m); i++)`, you end up with a negative number. Since 0 is greater than any negative number you never enter the loop.